# Debugging info in linux kernel - how does it work?

Tags: linux, kernel, debugging

I have found that I can compile linux kernel with some flags adding debugging support like CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO. These options while useful in debugging are also required by some utilities like SystemTap.

I was using SystemTap because it allowed me to get all syscalls from whole system (and won't hang it like tracing all processes using strace did).

I was wondering how these information are read from kernel (in the way that is not causing so big overhead).

Answer (score 0):

`CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO` is about building kernel with debugging symbols (for gdb or other debugger).  These are stored on disk separately from kernel itself, and are not read from running copy of kernel.